# Treating a Directory as a Single Module?

Tags: python

I am currently designing and implementing unit tests for my company's build scripts. I'm running into the issue that the unit test module is getting a bit large and I'd like to split it up into separate modules. However, this would make using the unit tests a bit more complicated (Users would have to know what module the desired tests are in and then append that module name to all functions), and I'd like to keep it as simple as possible for future use.

As I see it, there are two ways of dealing with this. I could either get tricky with namespaces - a feat that I would rather not try to accomplish - or I could find some way of handling all the modules in the testing directory as if they were contained in a single file. 
This would accomplish two goals: First, it would make future maintenance of the unit tests much easier, and second, it would simplify use of the unit test for the person who has to test the build scripts.

Is there any way of doing this in Python? Also, apologies if any of this is unclear. I'm new to Python so my terminology may not be correct.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, In your directory, create an `__init__.py` file, and import all the files into that.

```
-test_dir/
    __init__.py
    one.py
    two.py
```

in `__init__.py`

```
from one import A, B, C
from two import D, E, F
```

This way, your directory `test_dir` can be treated as a module.

Comment: By what name would I import that directory, then?

Comment: test_dir - the name of the directory.